# max min and average looking up file python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that asks for a name of a file, opens the file, and determines the maximum and minimum values in the files, and also computes the average of the numbers in the file.  I want to print the max and min values, and return the average number of values in the file.  The file has only one number per line, which consists of many different numbers top to bottom.  Here is my program so far:

```
def summaryStats():
    fileName = input("Enter the file name: ") #asking user for input of file
    file = open(fileName)
    highest = 1001
    lowest = 0
    sum = 0
    for element in file:
        if element.strip() > (lowest):
            lowest = element
        if element.strip() < (highest):
            highest = element
        sum += element
        average = sum/(len(file))
    print("the maximum number is ") + str(highest) + " ,and the minimum is " + str(lowest)
    file.close()
    return average
```

When I run my program, it is giving me this error:

```
summaryStats()
Enter the file name: myFile.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 8, in summaryStats
builtins.TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

I think I'm struggling determining which part to make a string.  What do you guys think?

Comment: Try struggling instead to determine which part to make an int :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines like these:

```
if element.strip() > (lowest):
```

Should probably be explicitly converting to a number. Currently you're comparing a `str` to and `int`. Converting using `int` will take whitespace into account, where `int('   1  ') is 1`

```
if int(element.string()) > lowest:
```

Also, you could do this like so:

```
# Assuming test.txt is a file with a number on each line.
with open('test.txt') as f:
    nums = [int(x) for x in f.readlines()]
    print 'Max: {0}'.format(max(nums))
    print 'Min: {0}'.format(min(nums))
    print 'Average: {0}'.format(sum(nums) / float(len(nums)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two incompatible types `str` and `int`.  You need a make sure you are comparing similar types.  You may want to rewrite your `for` loop to include a call to make sure you are comparing two `int` values.

```
for element in file:
    element_value = int(element.strip())
    if element_value > (lowest):
        lowest = element
    if element_value < (highest):
        highest = element_value
    sum += element_value
    average = sum/(len(file))
```

When python reads in files, it reads them in as type `str` for the whole line.  You make the call to `strip` to remove surrounding white space and newline characters.  You then need to parse the remaining `str` into the correct type (`int`) for comparison and manipulation.

You should read through your error messages, they are there to enlighten you on where and why your code failed to run.  The error message traces where the error took place. the line

```
File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 8, in summaryStats
```

Tells you to examine `line 8` which is the place for the error takes place.

The next line:

```
builtins.TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Tells you what is going wrong.  A quick search through the python docs locates the [description of the error](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError).  An easy way to search for advice is to look in the documentation for the language and maybe search for the entire error message.  It is likely you are not the first person with this problem and that there is probably a discussion and solution advice available to figure out your specific error.

Answer (score -2):

when you call open(filename), you are constructing a file object. You cannot iterate through this in a for loop.

If each value is on it's own line: after creating the file object, call:

```
lines = file.readlines()
```

Then loop through those lines and convert to int:

```
for line in lines: 
  value = int(line)
```